# Aptana - Preview in browser shortcut?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

[image: Preview in browser shortcut]

What's the shortcut for previewing in web-broswer for Aptana Studio 3? I have been looking all around, but still couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default keybinding for previewing the file, but you could define one from the Preferences > General > Key page and looking for "Show Preview":

[image]

Hope this helps.